# Set width of Switch

Tags: nativescript, angular2-nativescript, nativescript-angular

I am using Nativescript with Angular and I would like to set the width of a `Switch` element.

To do this I added:

```
style="width: 20%; min-width: 20%;"
```

To the element in the template.

But the width of the element doesn't change when I test it.

Why isn't it working?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Behind the NativeScript's `Switch` we have [android.widget.CompoundButton](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/CompoundButton) on Android and [UISwitch](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uiswitch?changes=_6&language=objc) on iOS. There is no option to change the width of the `Switch` widget but you can access the native element and modify its native width (if possible). As far as I've seen modifying the width of UISwitch is as simple as marshaling the below code to JavaScript

```
aSwitch.transform = CGAffineTransformMakeScale(2.0, 2.0);
```

In NativeScript you can access the native view (iOS or Android) via [`nativeView`](https://docs.nativescript.org/api-reference/classes/_ui_switch_.switch#nativeview) property.

For example (TypeScript):

```
let mySwitch= <Switch>page.getViewById("mySwith");
if (isIOS) {
    let iosSwitch = mySwitch.nativeView;
    iosSwitch.transform = CGAffineTransformMakeScale(2, 2);
}
```

Following the same principle, you could adopt a native Android solution to adjust the Android counterpart.

Comment: Thank's for your help. I am trying to do this for android but am having trouble. In my component I have used this to get my switches `@ViewChildren("switch") switches: QueryList<ElementRef>;`. There are 7 of them so I do `switches.forEach` to loop though them. In the loop I have tried to get both `switch.android` and `switch.nativeView` but both come back as undefined. I am doing this in the `ngAfterViewInit` life cycle hook. Why am I not able to get the native view?